# why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, ios8

I am new to IOS development. I am developing an app for IOS 8 devices. I used storyboard for my design yesterday my storyboard showing all UI design but today morning it show blank UIViewController no UI element vision please see in screen shot and very strange thing is that when i run my app all ui element visible in my device. I google but dont find any solution please help me out. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using size class and you went into a *particular* size class and added these views. Now you are back in *Any* size class, so the views are not there (that is why they are greyed out in the document outline at the left). They are available only for that *particular* size class. If you switch back to it again, whatever it was, you will see them again. Basically, you have created *conditional views* - the condition being that they are present only when that particular size class situation is the case.

In other words, if you want your layout to apply in the general case, you want to start by creating and editing it under *Any* size classes. Only then do you switch to a particular size class and *modify* the layout for that *particular* size class.

> when i run my app all ui element visible in my device

Yes, because on your device the particular size class situation matches the size class you were editing when you added those views. So there they are. That seems to me to prove my guess is right.

Comment: Good Answer.. Thank you very much

Comment: I changed it to wCompact hCompact and it works fine.

Comment: Awesome, been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: In my case, I was added my `ViewControllers` `UI` selecting `wCompact hRegular` and try to show them in `wAny hAny`. That's why the controllers were in disable mode. After changing it to `wCompact hRegular`, the controllers are now showing as usually.
Thanks :) @matt

Comment: My size classes is same but still not showing after copy the Viewcontroller to another.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue while copy a ViewController to another storyboard.

Fixed by following steps:

1: Select the viewController

2: Click on 5th Tab

3: Set the simulated size to Fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Select install:
Since all components [like label,textfield,buttons] are in disable mode, one select Installed check mark its will be enable again adjust constrain accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The size must be the same, in all xcode storyboard

Comment: Based on the other accepted answer, I have to say that you're incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to me setting alpha to 0.0 and forgetting it.