# Copy Storyboard across size classes

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have made a storyboard using "wCompact" (Compact Width) and "hRegular" (Regular Height") size class. Now when I change to "wAny"|"wHeight" all the components of on the storyboard to be specific that view controller disappears. I want to copy the same design for "wAny" (Any Width) and hAny ("Any Height") size class. How can I do it ? Right now I have placed no constraints on the design just layout. 
Is there any way to copy it. Following are images in "Compact Width" and "Regular Height"
Well  I have referred this too, [why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198661/why-storyboard-ui-elements-not-showing-on-uiviewcontroller-in-xcode-6) 
But i wanted to know if by any means copying across size classes is available in xcode6.

[image: Layout with "wCompact"|"hRegular"]
[image]

Comment: By autolayout means adding constraints .. but those will be specific to only iphone6 (compact width  | regular height")  and not for wAny | wHeight.

Comment: I mean that, right now i am using "wCompact" |"hRegualr" ... if i use ur approach then those constraints will remain only for "wCompact" |"hRegualr" and not apply to "wAny|WHeight"

Comment: Thanks for your efforts bhavin, seems i will have to design it again for "wAny|wHeight" combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you've done it wrong and you need to start over. Design the basic interface in Any/Any. What you do there will by default be true for all specific classes. Now design modifications to the basic interface in specific size classes.

Comment: Ya matt...but the thing is he doesn't use constraints.....so even if it makes in wAhA ....the views disappear on other specifications...

Comment: Well what matt says is true.

Comment: Means you want to say that if you make a view for wAhA ....the view not disappears in compact size?...if yes...then I don't agree with you without autolayout

Comment: Bhavin : It follows sub class hierarchy model. Sub Class hierarchy model .
By this it means that constraints will get applied to that size class and to more specific derived sub classes if any, but it will be uninstalled for the generic size classes going up the chain.

Comment: Question is NOT duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198661/why-storyboard-ui-elements-not-showing-on-uiviewcontroller-in-xcode-6 Question is about how to copy existing items from specific size class to other size class.