# iOS- Can Interface Builder instance outlets be preserved across size classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've developed an iOS application in xCode. I did most of the laying out (UIKit object instances, layout constraints etc.) on the storyboard. Initially, I thought it was meant to be an iPad app, so it was built with the Regular by Regular size class in the interface builder. Now, when I"m ready to release, I find it must support iPhones as well.

When jumping to the Any width by Any height layout, naturally all of my layouts disappear, but my model and control code are just fine. How should I best handle this? Can I salvage anything of my previous layouts?

Comment: I think this has already been answered. Please, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656114/copy-storyboard-across-size-classes

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to redo everything. Just go to your Regular-Regular size class, select all constraints like this [image]

and then in the attributes inspector install them all for any other size class that you want, like this:
[image]

Do it for all constraints and subviews.