# Xcode Main.storyboard not showing Items

Tags: xcode, swift, program-entry-point

I can't see items that add to my ViewController before like buttons but it shows in simulator and I tried to Select Identity Inspector of view and set Lock to Nothing but does not changing , How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quote from another post by matt could be helpful:

"It looks to me like you are using size class and you went into a particular size class and added these views. Now you are back in Any size class, so the views are not there (that is why they are greyed out in the document outline at the left). They are available only for that particular size class. If you switch back to it again, whatever it was, you will see them again. Basically, you have created conditional views - the condition being that they are present only when that particular size class situation is the case.

In other words, if you want your layout to apply in the general case, you want to start by creating and editing it under Any size classes. Only then do you switch to a particular size class and modify the layout for that particular size class.

when i run my app all ui element visible in my device
Yes, because on your device the particular size class situation matches the size class you were editing when you added those views. So there they are. That seems to me to prove my guess is right."

link is: [why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198661/why-storyboard-ui-elements-not-showing-on-uiviewcontroller-in-xcode-6)