# why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

Just one controller are not showing the elements, others working fine. i also take a help from [why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198661/why-storyboard-ui-elements-not-showing-on-uiviewcontroller-in-xcode-6/32350010?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but till same problem . Can any one suggest me how to resolve it? [image]

Comment: it seems there some waring in your view controller related to auto layout. try to fix and check.

Comment: @Shahbaz Akram Debugging the viewcontroller can be difficult sometimes due to many views in the hierarchy, you can copy the ui elements one by one and try to make a copy of it. Then check which ui element making the problem.

Comment: I create new controller and copy paste all views it. problem resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging the viewcontroller can be difficult sometimes due to many views in the hierarchy, you can copy the UIElements one by one and try to make a copy of it. Then check which UIElement making the problem.